# why when I add a multiple line does not save in database using HQL

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hql

I import the line from xlsx
just the last line saved in a database!

here the result after I run the code the first line is an insert and the second and third line update!

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into libraries (account_name, area, branch, currency, deported, employee, invoice_number, monetary, month, movement_type, metal, profit_local_currency, profit_ratio, total, total_local_currency, total_metal, libraries_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
Hibernate: update libraries set account_name=?, area=?, branch=?, currency=?, deported=?, employee=?, invoice_number=?, monetary=?, month=?, movement_type=?, metal=?, profit_local_currency=?, profit_ratio=?, total=?, total_local_currency=?, total_metal=? where libraries_id=?
Hibernate: update libraries set account_name=?, area=?, branch=?, currency=?, deported=?, employee=?, invoice_number=?, monetary=?, month=?, movement_type=?, metal=?, profit_local_currency=?, profit_ratio=?, total=?, total_local_currency=?, total_metal=? where libraries_id=?
```

this is my code to import from xlsx:

```
public void button(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String s = "";

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\yosef\\Desktop\\test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            int count = 0;
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        s = cell.getStringCellValue() + "";
                        if (count == 0) {
                            lib.setMonth(s);
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                            lib.setMonetary(null);
                        } else if (count == 3) {
                            lib.setDeported(s);
                        } else if (count == 4) {
                            lib.setMovementType(s);
                        } else if (count == 5) {
                            lib.setArea(s);
                        } else if (count == 6) {
                            lib.setAccountName(s);
                        } else if (count == 7) {
                            lib.setCurrency(s);
                        } else if (count == 9) {
                            lib.setMtal(s);
                        } else if (count == 15) {
                            lib.setEmployee(null);
                            lib.setBranch(s);
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        s = cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
                        if (count == 1) {
                            lib.setInvoiceNumber(Double.parseDouble(s));
                        } else if (count == 8) {
                            lib.setTotal(s);
                        } else if (count == 10) {
                            lib.setTotalMetal(s);
                        } else if (count == 11) {
                            lib.setTotalLocalCurrency(Double.parseDouble(s));
                        } else if (count == 12) {
                            lib.setProfitLocalCurrency(s);
                        } else if (count == 13) {
                            lib.setProfitRatio(Double.parseDouble(s));
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                }
                if (count != 15)
                    count++;




        }
            if (!ConnectionUtil.getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                ConnectionUtil.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            }

            ConnectionUtil.getEntityManager().persist(lib);
            ConnectionUtil.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: You seem to be reusing the same `lib` instance.

Comment: how is this related to javafx (except accidentally happening from an action handler)? Solve it in isolation (hard-coded, no ui), then merge into ui.

Comment: but I don't have any error in my UI or hard-coded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should but this line

```
libraries lib = new libraries();
```

under this line

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
```

because I use one object for all rows, and when I create one object for one row, I solved this problem.